# Github pages fails to deal with redirection on ghosted url

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages

I have a project site on Github pages.  It's available through this URL:

https://joereddington.github.io/CommuniKate/

To make things a little more pretty, I have the domain communikate.equalitytime.co.uk 'ghosted' by Dreamhost to point to the Github site.

However, subpages are having a problem.

This works fine: http://joereddington.github.io/CommuniKate/demos/CK20V2/ and shows the project demo.

But http://communikate.equalitytime.co.uk/demos/CK20V2/ gives 404.

I'm interested to know if anyone can tell me:

- **Why this is happening,**
- **and how can I fix it?**

In case it's useful,  my _config for Jekyll is this:

```
# ----------------------- #
#      Main Configs       #
# ----------------------- #

url: http://yoursite.com
title: CommuniKate
email: info@communikate.joereddington.com
author: Joe Reddington
description: > # "Write an awesome description for your new site here. 
  You can edit this line in _config.yml. It will appear in your document 
  head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site 
  description.
copyright: 'Copyright &copy; 2016 Your Name. All Rights Reserved.'
credits: 'Credits: Landing Page is a free to use, open source Bootstrap theme created by <a href="http://startbootstrap.com/">Start Bootstrap</a>.'

# ----------------------- #
#    Jekyll & Plugins     #
# ----------------------- #

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
permalink: pretty

# ----------------------- #
#   3rd Party Settings    #
# ----------------------- #

social:
  - title: twitter
    url: https://twitter.com/CommunikateAAC
  - title: github
    url: https://github.com/joereddington/CommuniKate
  - title: email
    url: mailto:info@communikate.joereddington.com
```

and the github repo itself is available [here](https://github.com/joereddington/CommuniKate/commits?author=joereddington)

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your DNS setup at dreamhosts.

```
$ dig communikate.equalitytime.co.uk
;; ANSWER SECTION:
communikate.equalitytime.co.uk. 14307 IN A  208.97.187.158
```

208.97.187.158 is not a github IP address.

You can try to use [github documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-subdomain/) for a successful setup.

**Notes** :

- There is no links to your demos on the home page.
- You're loading 33.4 MB of images. This is not fair for datas plans. [This is what's the cost for people around the globe to visit your home page](https://whatdoesmysitecost.com/test/160714_KE_377ce4d12c0391f9426bb527d1af5381).

Nevertheless, communikate is nice and useful job.

Comment: What an amazingly interesting website! Also what's the deal with Canada?  Thank you - will check out Dreamhost and come back.

Comment: For costs, most interesting view is the one who compares cost with revenues by day https://whatdoesmysitecost.com/test/160714_KE_377ce4d12c0391f9426bb527d1af5381#gniCost